# Python program to find the factorial of a number using recursion

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, recursion

A factorial of a number is the product of all the integers from `1` to that number.

For example, the factorial of `5` (denoted as `5!`) is `1*2*3*4*5 = 120`. The factorial of `0` is `1`.

```
def recur_factorial(x):

    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (x * recur_factorial(x - 1))

num = int(input("Enter number: "))

print("The factorial of", num, "is", recur_factorial(num))
```

So I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Also, I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of recursion.

Comment: `The factorial of 0 is 1.` What does this code do for `x==0`?

Comment: @MaartenFabré - I have edited my code to include your question above.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Once a question has an answer, leave the code in it alone. If the original code wasn't complete, please learn something from this for your next question.

Comment: @MaartenFabré - `if num == 0: print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")`

Comment: @Mast - Thank you, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking over your code, this is what I have for you:

- Your function can be turned into a one-liner
- You should use `if __name__ == '__main__'` to ensure you're not running this program externally.

Refactored Code:

```
def recur_factorial(x):
  return 1 if x == 1 else (x * recur_factorial(x - 1))

def main():
  num = int(input("Enter number: "))
  print("The factorial of", num, "is", recur_factorial(num))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

You can read [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250733/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-recursion) for more information about the advantages and disadvantages of recursion